# labview while loop execution condition

Tags: while-loop, labview

Is there a way to give while loop a condition which makes it give an an output every ten times' executions, however it continues running after this output?

I hope I made myself clear...

Thanks!

Amy

Answer (score 3):

Modulo is useful for this.

As an example; In swift to do modulo you use the % symbol. Essentially modulo outputs the remainder of the given terms.

So;

`Value 1 MODULO Value 2 outputs Remainder`.

Furthermore;

- 6 % 2 = 0
- 6 % 5 = 1
- 6 % 4.5 = 1.5

Essentially you want every nth element to output a value, with n being the rate. You need to track how many loops of the while you have gone through already.

The code below will run through the while 1000 times, and print out every 10 times ( for a total of 100 prints of output. )

```
var execution : Int = 0
while ( execution != 1000 ) {
    if ( execution % 10 == 0 ) {
        print("output")
    }
    execution = execution + 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam, any idea how can I implement it in LabVIEW?

Comment: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/3F2D557CB192B1B286256FAB00809E00

Comment: Thank you very much! this is of great help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same answer as given by adam but then in Labview.

[image]